# Нужно соединить два объекта в css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, веб-дизайн

В общем, я создал кнопку и отдельно от неё стрелку. Стрелка имеет ховер поворота вправо и изменение прозрачности с 0% до 100%. **Хочу, чтобы при наведении на кнопку срабатывал эффект ховера стрелки.** Код ниже.

```
.button {
   display: inline-block;

   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 10px;

   cursor: pointer;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 5px;

   font-size: 14px;
}

.arrow {
   display: inline-block;

   margin-left: 10px;

   opacity: .0;
   transition: 1s;
}

.right {
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   transition: all 0.2s;
}

.right:hover {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition: all 0.4s;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: вы бы приложили верстку еще чтобы было понятнее как они друг к другу относятся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.button:hover ~ .right{
transform: rotate(0deg);
transition: all 0.4s;
opacity: 1;}
```

p.s. чтоб работало кнопка и стрелка должны иметь общего родителя.